# How to always display a specific post from the search result first

Tags: filters, taxonomy, order

I created a search filter that displays posts randomly, and I wonder how can I always display a specific post item in the first position of the search results and display the rest of the items normally.

```
$taxonomies = array('recipe_type', 'product_category', 'recipe_category', 'recipe_event', 'recipe_diet');

foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
    $taxonomies_taxonomy[$taxonomy] = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
    $taxonomies_terms[$taxonomy] = get_terms(
        array(
        'taxonomy'      => $taxonomy,
        'hide_empty'    => false,
        'meta_key'      => 'filter_order',
        'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'         => 'ASC'
        )
    );
    $taxonomies_selected[$taxonomy] = (get_query_var($taxonomy)) ? get_query_var($taxonomy) : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to show a specific post always first is to add a sorting loop between your post query and rendering loop.

For example,

```
$my_posts = array(); // do your query first to get the posts

$sorted_posts = array(); // helper var to store sorted posts

// The sorting loop
foreach ( $my_posts as $post ) {
    if ( "some logic here" ) {
        array_unshift($sorted_posts, $post); // use php function to prepend the post to the sorted array
    } else {
        $sorted_posts[] = $post; // just push the posts to the end of the sorted array
    }
}

// use $sorted_posts array in your rendering (foreach/while/for) loop
```